# Net::FTP File Delete Get Stuck at Sometime

Tags: ruby, net-ftp

I used `Net::FTP` to upload and remove files in my server. When i try to delete a file, it sometimes get stuck. Can anyone explain me why this is happening.

```
ftp.delete(file)
```

Comment: Can you find out what error messages you are getting? A network error maybe?

Comment: It just hang, no response is coming.

Comment: try setting the read_timeout option and see if that raises a TimeoutError

Comment: After setting timeout i will raise timeout error. @Anthony

Comment: Why it got stuck there, can you explain. Is there any reason for this. @Anthony

Comment: your server is taking a long time to respond.  you can keep increasing the timeout time to meet your needs

Comment: Any other reason can cause this problem @Anthony